# Typescript : check string variable value is part of property name of class given as type T

Tags: typescript, factory, typescript-generics

I've created a factory checking that property given exists in my class A.

This works :

```
nameOf<A>("name")
```

So given the string it works but I can't make it working when using a variable (dynamic) :

```
nameOf<A>(this.filters.orderCode) // this.filters.orderCode can contain "id", "name", ... so properties of my A class
```

Error message : Argument of type "string" is not assignable to parameter of type "id" | "name" | ...
My nameOf factory :

```
export const nameOf = <T>(name: keyof T) => name;
```

My object A class :

```
export class A {
  id: number = 0;
  name = '';
  ...
}
```

**EDIT**

The nameOf factory give the opportunuity to the intellisense to show the list of my model properties in addition to verifying it exists in it : 
[image]

I'm using typescript 3.2.4

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: can you omit `keyof T` and use `any` instead

Comment: Not clear how your `nameOf` works, but type should probably be `PropertyKey` instead of `keyof T` if you want to allow passing any keys

Comment: both propositions doesn't raise me the expected error when my value is not matching a property of class A. 
Expected : If "this.filters.orderCode" = "name" it should work wheras when this.filters.orderCode = "nam" it should not work as missing in class A.
I've edited the nameOf to reduce to keep it minimal as possible.